# SpringBoot custom spring.config.location

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a simple SpringBoot application with the following structure:

[image]

I'm using a standard application.yml file where I'm storing all the necessary props and use @ConfigurationProperties annotation to inject them where necessary.

Now for one bean I have quite a lot of props and I don't want to overwhelm my common application.yml file with all that props. So I want a separate one (which I placed under service dir in classpath).

According to Spring docs I can use something like:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/service/application.yml
```

But that's not working, I got NullPointer which means property was not injected.
What Am I doing wrong? How can I use another *.yml file together with application.yml?

P.S. I know I could place it under the config folder in classpath, but what if I need two custom files?

Comment: if you do this the common application.yml(under /resources) will be ignored. There might be some bean using properties from this yml resulting in NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 configs in different places, spring.config.location will accept a comma separated list of those locations

```
--spring.config.location=classpath:/resources/,classpath:/service/
```

You could also just call the other file like "config.yml" and then use a different name

```
--spring.config.name=application,config
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot for examples! That worked for me

Comment: Yeah, sorry, earlier I wasn't allowed to vote because of low reputation. Now I can) thanks again!